# While loop in while loop

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

THANKS FOR THE ANSWERS, I am really glad.. I edited the code and I want to ask, if I edited it well? :-)

```
  $result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `topic` ;");
                    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
                    {
                    $id=$row->id;
                    $photo=$row->photo;
                    $title=$row->title;
                    $shortinfo=$row->shortinfo;
                    echo"<div id='article'>
                        <a href='reporty.php?page=$id'><div id='article_img'><img src='$photo'/></div></a>
                        <div id='article_text'>
                        <h2>$title</h2>
                        <p>$shortinfo</p>
                        </div>
                        </div>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should set the second query as `$result1` because the new one is replacing the first one.. That's why you have always just one result

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM `topic` ;");
while($row = $result->fetch_object())
{
   $id=$row->id;                     
   echo '<div id="article">
            <a href="';
   echo '.php"><div id="article_img"><img src="';
   $result1 = $sql->query("SELECT `photo` FROM `topic` WHERE id='$id' ;");
   while ($row1 = $result->fetch_array()) {
       echo $row1['photo'];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result` and `$row` same variable name is used in both loops.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use readable and self-explanatory variable names, like `$photo_result` and `$title_result`. This then would also solve your problem since you use the same variable names in your loops.

For the sake of performance and simplicity, why don't you `JOIN` your tables? Then you'd only have one query with one loop.

Answer (score 0):

Give proper variable name always. Your `$result and $row` is holding all most all variable here.

Same memory location will be updated always. So it loses the old values (We learned this in 1st year degree/ PUC first year)

Do it like this,

for example when you are fetching from `topic` table and you select `photo`,

use variables like `$topicResultForPhto and`$topicPhotoRow`. Do this for all.

And one more error,

You already calls like `SELECT *` and you have all the fields from table. Why should again a call from `photo` and other fields like `select photo from topics where` ?